# Trying to come up with a good hashing algorithm for specific set of int data

Tags: algorithm, hash

I am trying to improve a hashtable implementation at the moment.  This hash table creates a custom hash and then does the typical routine of throwing it in the buckets and trying to find a place to shove it etc.

In my particular case, I have 2 numbers that span between the range of -16000 and 16000 each, and then one that spans from 0 to 256.

Effectively I have 2 shorts and 1 byte of extra data.  I am trying to make a good hashing algorithm for these sets of data.  I would prefer to have a flat map that doesn't dynamically grow and chew more memory, but the set of data is just too large in this case.

Any advice would be appreciated, I am not very experienced in this area at the moment.

EDIT: This is what the application uses to currently generate it's unique hashes:

```
public static int a(int i, int j, int k) {
  return j & 255 | (i & 32767) << 8 | (k & 32767) << 24 | (i < 0 ? Integer.MIN_VALUE : 0) | (k < 0 ? '\u8000' : 0)
}
```

Please note, I did not write this.  I am investigating how to improve it.

Comment: How many inputs are you expecting? What about the distribution of data?

Comment: Creating good hashes is *hard*. There are *many* places for a custom hash to go wrong, and creating one that provides random or nearly-random output for general input is a task that takes time and a very good grasp on theory. However, if you are working on a hash for a very specific use case, then you might consider a custom algorithm.

Comment: Just wondering, what's wrong with existing hashes? Most of them do a pretty good job already.

Comment: @RedAlert there are 3 inputs, the 2 numbers from -16000 to 16000, and then one from 0 to 256.  The distribution of data can be anywhere inbetween these constraints

Comment: @user3580294 Trying to make something that is more specific to the dataset I am working with to improve performance.

Comment: @MasterGberry Yeah, I might have been a bit harsh... My apologies. So you want something like `hashCode()` but with a smaller output range?

Comment: @user3580294 yeah, looking to try and make a better `hashCode()` to make lookups more reliable and faster (would rather waste extra memory to get more close to O(1) lookups)

Comment: @MasterGberry Are you using the default `HashMap` implementation?

Comment: @user3580294 It looks like you are talking about cryptographic hashes, which isn't what the OP needs. His outputs only need to be unique...randomness doesn't matter

Comment: I imagine pretty much the best we can do with the given information is just give you a generic hash function. We need **distributions**, not just ranges. Do you have a strong reason to believe some hash function, even a simple one such as `(num1*31*31 + num2*31 + num3) % size`, doesn't give you the required performance, or are you just trying to [prematurely optimize](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization "ROOT OF ALL EVIL!!!")?

Comment: @RedAlert Looks to me like the input space is too large to fit into a 32-bit integer. But yeah, I was assuming too much...

Comment: @MasterGberry If you are only expecting 3 total inputs, you don't need a hashmap at all. How many exclusive inputs do you expect to handle with this data structure? Also, what does the distribution of the inputs look like? "anywhere inbetween these constraints" doesn't answer that question, if you don't know what a "distribution" is you should find out...otherwise you have no chance of creating a good hashing algorithm.

Comment: @RedAlert The distribution is pretty much spread evenly.  It does not lean towards one specific section very much.

Comment: @Dukeling I have edited my above post with the current hash function that is being used, which I did not write.

Comment: @MasterGberry What's deficient about the current hash implementation?

Comment: @user3580294 the get times do not seem to be performing too well, which leads me to believe that it's having to go through multiple buckets instead of just landing in one each time (which of course is an ideal scenario)

Comment: @MasterGberry Let me try testing that hash function... Is it first two arguments are `short`s, and last one is a `byte`?

Comment: if your distribution is really constant for 32000*32000*256 possibilities, your hash algorithm is either going to take up a ton of space, or have a lot of collisions. There's really no way around that.

Comment: @RedAlert That's what I fear, but I thought I would ask around first before coming to that conclusion.

Comment: @user3580294 effectively in my case. even though the function takes 3 ints, those are the extra constraints I am adding on top of it.

Comment: @MasterGberry All right. Working on a distribution test right now. If the test shows an even distribution then there isn't really much you can hope for in terms of improvement. Will report back. Probably will be an answer with source code.

Comment: You have 5 bytes of data.  If the data are truly uniformly distributed accross the range you've given, then just pack them into a long with `((i + 16000) * 32000) + (k + 16000)) * 256 + j`.  If they are liable to clump, but you have no idea how in advance, then you are best with a heuristic "bit-mixer" of the kind used for identifiers in compilers.  I've had good luck with the ones discussed here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.programming/HPveDbKmx38/kf967XHGD6oJ  . Just treat the 5 bytes as characters.  The `unsigned long` in this C code is equivalent to the `int` of a Java `hasCode`.

Comment: @Gene that would take up an enormous amount of space. You are looking at 2^38 possibilities. If each entry is only one byte, the data structure is still going to take up 256 GB of memory...not particularly feasible.

Comment: @MasterGberry Have you *measured* the load on your hash table? You can easily get a first idea of whether your hash function works reasonably well by checking the variance of the load factor in the different slots. For a good hash function, you're looking for a mean and variance of around n/s where n is the number of items and s is the number of slots. That's a binomial distribution.

Comment: @RedAlert Of course the `int` hash value is modulo the table size.  Java takes care of that.  He said in an earlier comment he's trying to replace `hashCode`, the Java base object hash function.